# Discover output class from json.net

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm doing a project where I dynamically build a set of objects based on reflection and serialize it (using json.net).

What I want to do is to deserialize it and recreate the object tree, but I don't know the final class type.

So how can I find out?

Here's an example:

```
    public class insideBleah
{
    public int BProperty
    { get; set; }
}

public class bleah
{
    public int AProperty
    { get; set; }

    public insideBleah Inside
    { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
    var bleah = new bleah();
    bleah.AProperty = 1;
    bleah.Inside = new insideBleah();
    bleah.Inside.BProperty = 2;

    var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bleah, new JsonSerializerSettings()
        {
            TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
});
```

This produces the output string:

```
"{\"$type\":\"jsontest.bleah, jsontest\",\"AProperty\":1,\"Inside\":{\"$type\":\"jsontest.insideBleah, jsontest\",\"BProperty\":2}}"
```

So I can see the class in there.  It's so close!  But I can't seem to tease the information out.

How can I do this?  I can't do:

```
var newObject = (bleah)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<bleah>(output);
```

because I don't know it's a 'bleah'.

How can I handle this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: To be clear, if I can figure out how to access the value of the $type attribute (if I'm reading this correctly - I'm really new at it) I should be able to create the objects myself.  But then what good is the  deserializer doing me?

Answer (score 1):

Why can you just use:

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var bleah = new Person();
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings {  TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects };
            var output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(bleah, settings);

            Console.WriteLine(output);

            var deserializeObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output, settings);
            Console.WriteLine(deserializeObject.GetType().Name);

        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The output:

```
{"$type":"ConsoleApplication1.Person, ConsoleApplication1","Name":null}
Person
```

Comment: Because after I deserialize I need to reflect on the type in order to look at decorators (attributes) in order to determine what to do with it.  I think I can't do this with dynamic

Comment: @jackjumper, in that case, just replace `dynamic` with `object`.

Comment: svick is rigth, you can use `newObject.GetType()` and it will return your real type.

Comment: So I do var newObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(output) - remember in my real case I don't know the type.  Then I look at newObject.GetType() and it gives me: {Name = "JObject" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject"}